# Regular Expression for Redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I’m looking for a regular expression that can redirect anything that a particular folder contains, e.g.:

`website.com/tags/…` --> (character or number that comes after `/tags/`)

I want to redirect anything that comes after `/tags/` to the main website.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this on your own?

Comment: I am not even sure what you are trying to do and what it has to do with RegExes. Could please explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

If this is python you are talking about, you can use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) in order to replace any occurence of

```
website.com\\tags\\.+
```

with

```
website.com

s1 = "www.website.com\tags\1234"
s1 = re.sub('website.com\\tags\\.+', "website.com", s1")
```

the **.+** checks for any characters after the tags\ part of the string. If they exist, replace the whole string with **website.com**

This is just a python solution, but it should work for any language that has a replace function in their regex library. Regardless, if it is the regex you are curious about, you're looking for **website.com\\tags\\.+**

Answer (score 0):

No idea what exactly you're asking but it sounds like you want something like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/tags/ /
```

Which does precisely this:

> Basically i want to redirect anything that comes after /tags/ t the main website.

Assuming what you mean by the main website is **website.com/**